# ERROR TypeError: value.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I need to create an update from in angular 6  with FormArray .

I use this code in `editfrom.TS` :

```
  valueIngrident=new FormArray([]);

    constructor(private brandService:BrandService,private PValueInfoService:ProductinfovalueService,private productinfoService:ProductinfoService,private catService:CategoryService,private produSrvice:ProductService, private route:ActivatedRoute,private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.id= + this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.productVM=this.produSrvice.InitialProduct();

   }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.InitialForm()
    this.GetMainCat();
    }

  InitialForm(){
    this.editFG=this.fb.group({
      productTitle:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      productName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      color:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      productImageName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      price:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      gurantyMonth:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      gurantyCompanyName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      catId:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      brandId:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      values:this.valueIngrident
    })
    this.GetProductByID(this.id)
  }

  public GetProductByID(id:number){
    this.produSrvice.GetProductDetailById(id).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.productVM=data
      this.SelectBrand=data.brandId
      this.SelectCat=data.catId
      this.PName=this.productVM.productName
      this.editFG.setValue({
        productTitle:[data.productTitle],
        productName:[data.productName],
        color:[data.color],
        productImageName:[data.productImageName],
        price:[data.price],
        gurantyMonth:[data.gurantyMonth],
        gurantyCompanyName:[data.gurantyCompanyName],
        catId:[data.catId],
        brandId:[data.brandId],
        values:this.valueIngrident
      })
      this.ChangeFormByType(data.catId)
  })
  }

  get ValueFormControl(){
    return  this.editFG.get('values') as FormArray;
}

  public CreateValueFiled(PD:Productinfovalue[]){
    for(let element of PD )
    {
      this.valueIngrident.push(
        new FormGroup({
          infoId:new FormControl(element.infoId),
          value:new FormControl(element.value)
        })
      )
    }
}

  public ChangeFormByType(id:number){
    this.ChangeBrand(id)
      this.PValueInfoService.GetAllInfoValueForUpdate(id).subscribe(
        res=>{
          this.PD=res,
          this.CreateValueFiled(this.PD)
        }
      )
  }
```

And I use that in HTML :

```
                <div class="form-inline lbin" formArrayName="values">
                <div class="form-inline lbin" *ngFor="let valueCtrl of ValueFormControl.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div  class="form-inline lbin">
                        <label></label> 
                        <input formControlName="value" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But when the page is loading it shows me this Error :

> ERROR TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
>       at FormArray.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormArray.setValue (forms.js:3545)

What is the problem?

Comment: The return from `this.editFG.get('values')` needs to be checked as it is not an array. You should defensively test that return since is is from an uncontrolled source. If not valid then throw and handle or return an empty array.

Comment: What is `this.valueIngrident` ?

Comment: @User5842 `valueIngrident=new FormArray([])`

Comment: @RandyCasburn the `values` is form Array

Comment: @Mr-Programer - read the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormArray has the function setValue. The first parameter should be an array. You are sending an object.

See the middle of your function `GetProductByID(id:number)`
Here you call `this.editFG.setValue({...})`

[From the official documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray):

> setValue(value: any[], options: { onlySelf?: boolean; emitEvent?:
>   boolean; } = {}): void Parameters  value  any[]    Array of values for
>   the controls
>
> options  object   Configure options that determine how the control
>   propagates changes and emits events after the value changes
>
> onlySelf: When true, each change only affects this control, and not
>   its parent. Default is false. emitEvent: When true or not supplied
>   (the default), both the statusChanges and valueChanges observables
>   emit events with the latest status and value when the control value is
>   updated. When false, no events are emitted. The configuration options
>   are passed to the updateValueAndValidity method. Optional. Default is
>   {}.
>
> Returns void

Your parameter is wrapped in a {}, which makes it an object. And the function specifications says it needs to be an array.

The setValue function calls forEach on the array, and there is no forEach for objects, which is why it says that value.forEach is not a function.